# Correct usage of 'was not having' or 'did not have'?

Tags: tenses

Is the sentence 'The man was not having any change' grammatically correct? Or does I have to be 'did not have'?

Answer (score 4):

*Stative* verbs like *have*, *be*, *love* are not ordinarily used in progressive constructions, at least in part because one function of the progressive is to ‘recategorize’ an eventive as a stative and statives are of course already stative. When they *are* used in the progressive, they have somewhat different meanings:

> He's being an idiot *does not mean* He is an idiot *but* He's behaving like an idiot.
>
> I'm loving it! *does not mean* I love it *but* I am enjoying it greatly.
>
> I'm not having it *does not mean* I don't have it *but* I refuse to accept it.

In your sentence *have* is used in its ordinary sense *possess*, so it should not be cast in the progressive.

Answer (score 2):

Neither usage is technically incorrect, but they carry slightly different meanings. Almost always, "did not have" is what you intend. A native English speaker would almost never use "was not having", and certainly not in that context.

Comment: I'm not having that!

Comment: @TimLymington Exactly! It has a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It is grammatically correct, but it doesn't make logical sense. What is the act of not having any change that this man was engaged in?